# Merging two circles when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are two circles (two `divs`) in the webpage. What I want is when I scroll down , it should move both the circles like I mentioned below in the image.

[Circles_Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy750.jpg)

Its just like a venn diagram. When both the two circles got merged , it should create a new region as mentioned in the image and we should be able to write something inside it. Is it possible using HTML with CSS or do we need jQuery also. I have also seen some examples related to skrollr framework but I didn't understand how to use it properly.

Comment: To highlight the intersection of divs a complex question and moving circles on scroll is another complex question. I suggest posting two different questions with exact details and sample code that you have tried. No one will start writing codes in stackoverflow they just help you find why your codes are not working. Please read the help center and check how you should ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help Regards.

Comment: Thanks Ali for this information. I will ask a separate question for this intersection requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Javascript (or in your case: JQuery as an extension) 100%.
So here is what you need to do to get the circles closer together while scrolling:

First of all you set the `scroll` event listener. Detect if the user is scrolling up or down (there are a lot of tutorials out there about how to do that).

What you need now is to calculate. For each scroll event fired you can (for exmaple) add `0.1` to a variable. So if I scroll `10px` down my variable will have a value of `1`. This rule applies if the user is scrolling down.
If the user is scrolling up you need to subtract `-0.1` for each scroll event that is fired.

This variable will change the CSS-attributes of your circles. I would recommend using `position: relative` on both circles and `left: your_var` on the left circle and `right: your_var` on the right circle. In this way the circles move closer together if you scroll down.

```js
var between = 0;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$circle = $(".circle");
$left = $(".left");
$right = $(".right");
$(document).scroll(function() {

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    between += 0.7;
  } else {
    between -= 0.7;
  }
  scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  $left.css({
    left: between + "px",
    top: scrollTop + "px"
  });
  $right.css({
    right: between + "px",
    top: scrollTop + "px"
  });
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100000px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle left">1</div>

  <div class="circle right">2</div>
</div>
```

To your textarea inside the merging area:
This is stuff for another question as it is a rather complex one.

Comment: Do you know how to stop translation of the circle when it crosses the 50% of the window width?

Comment: Well, you will have to read out the window width and set it as a variable.
You need a resize event listener for that since the window width can change.

But keep in mind that this is all very performance consuming.